# Einstein bot: Redirect before a question choice is selected

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I have a basic dialog with our Einstein chatbot that uses the Object Search action to run a user's question through our knowledge base and provide 3 knowledge article options. Because we use the "Question" dialog option to present the answers, a user must  select one of the provided article options to make the chat move on.

If none of the articles are helpful, I'd like an option for the user to say "no" or choose a "none of these" option.

The Knowledge results are an Object variable, so when I choose that as the question entity/variable, the question choice type is automatically changed to dynamic, without the option to edit the choices.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As a current solution, I still include the object search, and then send the top 3 results as a message first (instead of a question).
[image: Message to present results]

Then the question element just asks the user to type the number that corresponds to the result that is best for them.

Rules say "if KnowledgeChoice = 1, send a message "Okay, here's the info Knowledge_Results[0].URLName" A final rule says that if KnowledgeChoice is NOT equal to 1, 2, or 3, redirect to dialog to start a case.
[image: Final Rule]